# Li-Ion 26650 battery holder

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I'm going to use [26650 Li-Ion batterys](http://www.tensai.com/index.php/products/rechargeable-batteries/li-ion-batteries/tr-26650li) with a suitable [battery charger IC](http://www.ti.com/product/bq24702) in my hardware. I'm looking for an adequete battery holder for two 26650 batterys like [this](https://content.solarbotics.com/products/photos/42b6d3bead98a923fe9fc289c3ff0af1/lrg/bholdaa.jpg) for AA batterys. But I find only [3D printed](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Dual-26650-battery-holder-sled-tray-3d-Printed-USA-Seller-Same-Day-Ship-/181682961982?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a4d25fe3e) or [modded](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dual-26650-Black-Battery-Holder-Sled-for-Box-Mod-1590B-/151614729987?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item234cf12f03) battery holders for 26650 with no connection to the battery poles in it. They are relatively expensive, and I have to solder to the pols of  the batterys. The direct soldering of these batterys is not recommended, that is why I'm looking for a holder like the AA batterys have.

Could someone suggest a holder for 26650 batterys like the AA batterys have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with 26650 batteries is they're not normally intended to be interchangeable like AA batteries.  They are most often found with solder tabs spot welded to the ends and either hard wired into a battery pack (such as for a laptop battery) or soldered direct to a PCB.

Being rechargeable they don't need replacing, so there is no need to add the expense of a battery holder.

However, that doesn't mean it's impossible.

You can buy PCB mount contacts for AA batteries, which are similar in size, such as these: http://uk.farnell.com/keystone/590/battery-holder-aa-n-1way/dp/1339844 and build up your own battery holder on a PCB.  You may need to adjust the sprung leaf a little to get to the right level for the battery contact, but it's certainly a possibility.  You would, of course, need some side support to keep the battery in place, but I'm sure a creative mind like yours could come up with something that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a battery holder / clip thing for CR123 batteries which there are no normal sized clips for (that I could find) and I quite easily managed to position these types of holders: [image]

So that it was able to hold the batteries securely.

I mounted it on a bit of vero-board but could equally be modified so that it was free floating with a bit of dab handed gluing and plastic cutting.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up makeing a tube from thick foil and glue gun for 2x 26650 contacts using copper 1.5mm coiled with a spring in the middle for springiness not tryed it yet tho but will be adding nichrome ribbon with a fuse ......just so I can power relays and lights on me ebike need about 3amp 12v when I pull brakes with the help of a boost converter I'm sick of 18650s lol